# can't get $state to work with angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I am trying to do a simple route redirect using `$state`.  I can't get it to work.  Here is my code:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ng-token-auth'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $location, $rootScope, $state) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function($state) {

    $rootScope.$on('auth:login-success', function($state) {
      console.log('success event triggered yo main');
      // $location.path('main');
      $state.go('main');
    });

  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive

  .state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'templates/main.html'
  })

  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
  })
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

});
```

This gives me the following error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 TypeError: $state.go is not a function
    at app.js:28
    at Scope.$broadcast (ionic.bundle.js:29477)
    at ng-token-auth.js:191
    at ionic.bundle.js:23384
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:27879)
    at ionic.bundle.js:27895
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:29158)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:28969)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:29263)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:23676)
```

I tried removing $state from $rootScope.$on but I got this error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined
    at app.js:28
    at Scope.$broadcast (ionic.bundle.js:29477)
    at ng-token-auth.js:191
    at ionic.bundle.js:23384
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:27879)
    at ionic.bundle.js:27895
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:29158)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:28969)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:29263)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:23676)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `$state` argument from the `$rootScope.$on`. I think it should be:

```
$rootScope.$on('auth:login-success', function() {
      console.log('success event triggered yo main');
      // $location.path('main');
      $state.go('main');
});
```

By passing the `$state` as an argument you are essentially doing this:

```
$rootScope.$on('auth:login-success', function($state) {
      var $state;
      console.log('success event triggered yo main');
      // $location.path('main');
      $state.go('main'); //undefined...
});
```

You may need to it from `$ionicPlatform.ready(function($state) {...` as well. You are defining the call back functions...not passing in `$state`. What you think is happening is not.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but it still doesn't work.  I've updated my question to include the new error message I get when I try doing that.

Comment: did you remove it from $ionicPlatform?

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work in the $rootScope now but I can't get it to work inside the specific routes.  For example, inside a ".state" i want to call $state so I can redirect if a user is not logged in.  any ideas?  I'm going to mark you right on this question and then post another one for this issue.

Comment: How do I tag you?  Here is the new issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482219/state-only-works-in-certain-parts-of-angular-app

Answer (score 0):

You need to set dependency to ui.router module:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', .... , 'ui.router'])
```