# $state only works in certain parts of angular app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I have gotten $state to work in one part of my application but not the other.  It works the first time I call it like this: `$state.go('main');` But I call it a little further down like this `$state.go('signIn');` and can't get it to work there.  What I want this code to do is if a user is not validated by `$auth.validator`, I want it to redirect to the sign in page with a message that says "You need to sign in". How do I do this?  Here is my code:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ng-token-auth'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $location, $rootScope, $state) {

    //I added in order to have redirect upon succesful login
    $rootScope.$on('auth:login-success', function() {
      console.log('success event triggered yo main');
      // $location.path('main');
      $state.go('main');
    });


})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider) {

  .state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
    resolve: {
      auth: ['$auth', function($auth) {
        console.log($auth.validateUser());
        return $auth.validateUser().catch(function(res) {
          console.log('in the validate user block');
          $state.go('signIn');
        });
      }]
    }
  })

  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
  })

  .state('signUp', {
    url: '/signup',
    templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
    controller: 'UserCtrl'
  })

  .state('signIn', {
    url: '/sign_in',
    templateUrl: 'templates/new_user_session.html',
    controller: 'UserCtrl'
  })

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

});
```

I get the folllowing error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 ReferenceError: $state is not defined
    at app.js:57
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:27879)
    at ionic.bundle.js:27895
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:29158)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:28969)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:29263)
    at bootstrapApply (ionic.bundle.js:14945)
    at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:17762)
    at doBootstrap (ionic.bundle.js:14943)
    at bootstrap (ionic.bundle.js:14963)
```

UPDATE:

I have figured out half of the problem.  I got $state to work by including it as a dependency:

```
auth: ['$auth', '$state', function($auth, $state) {
```

Now I just need to get the flash message to work and say "You need to sign in".

Comment: ok looks like you solved your own problem here.

Comment: Not the whole thing though :(

Comment: You must revise the question and post what you tried in order to get the flash message to show

Comment: I did revise.  Take a look at the end.  Also, any idea on this one?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486390/cant-access-a-view-within-a-state-in-angular-ui-router

Comment: If you are talking about "Now I just need to get the flash message to work and say "You need to sign in"." where is the code for the flash message?