# Cant access a view within a state in angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I am trying to link to a substate and can't figure out how to get it to work.  Here is the link:

```
<a ui-sref="tab.communityDashboard" class="button button-block button-large"><i class="icon ion-home"></i><br />Community Directory</a>
```

and here is the route:

```
  .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.communityDashboard', {
    url: '/communitydashboard',
    views: {
      'tab-communityDashboard': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

and then eventually:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

Here is the content of the view:

```
<ion-view view-title="tab-communityDashboard">
    <ion-content>
        yolo yolo yolo
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I tried also going to localhost:8100/#/communitydashboard but it just redirects me home.  How do I fix this.

Comment: But it's a child state of `tab` so why do you expect this to work: `localhost:8100/#/communitydashboard`? Maybe this will - `localhost:8100/#/tab/communitydashboard` But even if it doesn't - Do you have an element with `ui-view="tab-communityDashboard"` in your view?

Comment: does going to `localhost:8100/#/tab/communitydashboard` load the view?

Comment: Going to localhost:8100/#/tab/communitydashboard does not load the view.  it just redirects home.  I will load the content of the view into the question.  I think that may be the problem as I'm not really sure how this view system works.

Comment: I added the content of the view

Answer (score 0):

You need an `<ion-nav-view>` where you want your view to show up, and since you're using views with your states, you'll need to include the name attribute with the name of the view, so something like `<ion-nav-view name="tab-communityDashboard">`

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/